# Connecting two userid firebase database

Tags: android

I am making a cardview feed which consist firebase Pet
which has a layout like this

[image: Pet table]

Another table is the User

[image: User table]

I want to populate the cardview and Convert the UID from Pets to User name.

Heres my code

[image: code]

Comment: Please don't post screenshot of your source code. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53340709/edit) your question an paste the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
        new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(Model.class,R.layout.row,ViewHolder.class,mref)
        {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Model model, int position) {
                String userid = model.getUserid().toString();


                viewHolder.setDetails(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),model.getPetname(),"Reason:" + model.getReason(),model.getPetpicture(),"Breed:" + model.getBreed(),
                       "Age:  " + model.getAge(),"Size: " +  model.getPetsize() +"yrs old","Color:" + model.getPetcolor(),"",model.datepost);
            }
        };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

Comment: This code is working only posting the userid from the Pet